# How to add 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0' into my project dependencies corretly?

Tags: android

I added `'implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'` in build.gradle, but gradle project sync failed and gave me such error message:`ERROR: Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`. I wonder how to fix it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to go with Material Design, you should add:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

You can have both AndroidX and Material CardView:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Or

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use :

```
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
```

Instead of :

```
       implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

Comment: This is obsolete now!

Comment: No, you said that you did  implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0' and it's not the right way

Comment: Thank you for your help, project works with your method. However,i'm still confuesd that  in official documentation of Android, Google recommends us to use androidx instead of support library, how can i use androidx.cardview?

Comment: So please check it as the right answer to be useful for future visitors